# Google Drive Realtime API for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to implement realtime collaboration in my iOS app using Google Drive and the new realtime API.  I know that I can set up a web view in Objective-C and set up two-way communications between the web view and my native app, and therefore use the javascript library, but my fear is that this would be inefficient for a high volume of data traffic.  I was hoping that possibly there would be a native solution coming on the horizon.  Any news on whether the Google API client library for Objective-C will be updated to include the Google Drive Realtime API?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the Google real time api but for google drive integration  [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios)  would work. There is a sample app called Dr.Edit [here](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit).

Using UIWebView for doing all this stuff is not advised.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I have gone through the Google Drive API docs on the Google developer site, and that is a good example.  Problem is, I would like (need?) to integrate with the realtime API in Objective-C.  For now, the only way I can see to do this is through a UIWebView like [this](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/)

Comment: The link for Dr. Edit is dead.

Comment: @czechboy see the updated link.